# Facebook style notification date loop?

Tags: php, loops

I want to implement something like this in my website: [Facebook Notification](https://www.facebook.com/notifications)

But my problem is I cant manage to figure out the looping mechanism for:

1. Find the group with the same date today.
2. Then decrement the date by one, then group all the data with that date.
3. Decrement and group again.

Here's my data in array form:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [name] => test1
    [date] => 2013-07-15 04:02:53
)
[1] => Array (
    [name] => mine2
    [date] => 2013-07-15 03:24:57
)
[2] => Array (
    [name] => mine3
    [date] => 2013-07-12 04:19:59
)
[3] => Array (
    [name] => mine4
    [date] => 2013-07-11 05:05:38
)
[4] => Array (
    [name] => mine5
    [date] => 2013-07-10 05:05:38
)
[5] => Array (
    [name] => ffff
    [date] => 2013-07-10 05:02:38
)
[6] => Array (
    [name] => affff
    [date] => 2013-07-09 05:02:38
)
```

)

Anyone want to share their knowledge on how to group dates in a while/for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to loop through the data (assuming it is sorted by date) and group all items with the same date as follows:

```
$grouped_data = array();
$lastday = null;
foreach($data as $d){
    $thisday = strtotime(substr($d['date'],0,10));
    $grouped_data[$thisday][] = $d;
    if($thisday != $lastday)
        $lastday = $thisday;
}
```

Now all you have to do is loop through the days in the grouped data and display the items in each of them:

```
foreach($grouped_data as $day => $data){
    echo '<h2>'.date('M d', $day).'</h2>';
    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d['name'].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

If you want to display 'Today' or 'Yesterday' instead of the date then you could write a simple conditional to check if the current day you're looping is today or yesterday

```
$title = date('M d', $day);
if($title === date('M d')){
    $title = 'Today';
}elseif($title === date('M d',mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')-1))){
    $title = 'Yesterday';
}
```

Comment: Thank you koala_dev for your great solution!